# Make blogroll links no-follow?

Tags: blogroll

How can I add a nofollow option to my blogroll links editor?

Attempted to just type "nofollow" into the "rel" input box, but its auto deleted onblur.

If I turn javascript off (thanks to Matt's suggestion below), It works, but when I check the source on my site, the rel attribute looks like this...

rel="nofollow"onclick="javascript:pageTracker._trackPageview('/outbound/blogroll/www.site.com');

Comment: Are you just trying to nofollow certain links, or add a nofollow across the board? Its simple enough to filter the output of `wp list bookmarks` if that meets your needs...

Comment: all my blogroll links need to be nofollow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of three ways around this and unfortunately they all suck:

1. [Hack a core file](http://www.skatdesign.com/blog/seo/adding-nofollow-attribute-to-your-wordpress-blogroll.htm)
2. [Use a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=nofollow+blogroll)
3. Temporarily turn off scripgs in your browser and change them in the edit links section.

Comment: Of those, I like #3 best

Comment: How difficult would it be to add an option for "nofollow" to the Link editor's existing "Link Relationship(XFN) options list?

Comment: I think that's worthy of a new question.  It would be possible assuming theres a way to hook into it.  I don't know how but someone on here might.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your blogroll to make all links nofollow with a function like this:

```
function nofollow_blogroll( $html ) {
    // remove existing rel attributes
    $html = preg_replace( '/\s?rel=".*"/', '', $html );
    // add rel="nofollow" to all links
    $html = str_replace( '<a ', '<a rel="nofollow" ', $html );
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'wp_list_bookmarks', 'nofollow_blogroll' );
```

If you need to do it on a case-by-case basis, though, you're probably stuck with some hacks like @matt pointed out.